# Spyne- How to get element from SOAP

Tags: xml, soap, spyne

I'm using SPYNE for the very first time. I want write a server for TR069 service.

I receive message like below:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">
<soap-env:Header>
<cwmp:ID soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">984890494</cwmp:ID>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
<cwmp:Inform>
<DeviceId>
<Manufacturer>xxxx</Manufacturer>
<OUI>xxxxxx</OUI>
<ProductClass>x-xxxx-xx</ProductClass>
<SerialNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</SerialNumber>
</DeviceId>
<Event xsi:type="soap-enc:Array" soap-enc:arrayType="cwmp:EventStruct[1]">
<EventStruct>
<EventCode>2 PERIODIC</EventCode>
<CommandKey/>
</EventStruct>
</Event>
<MaxEnvelopes>1</MaxEnvelopes>
<CurrentTime>2014-05-21T10:47:37+08:00</CurrentTime>
<RetryCount>56</RetryCount>
<ParameterList xsi:type="soap-enc:Array" soap-enc:arrayType="cwmp:ParameterValueStruct[10]">
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SpecVersion</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.HardwareVersion</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3FE55918ABAA</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SoftwareVersion</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3FE55935ADEA19</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ProvisioningCode</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ConnectionRequestURL</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://x.x.x.x:7547/</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ParameterKey</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANIPConnection.1.ExternalIPAddress</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">10.18.92.182</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANIPConnection.1.MACAddress</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
</ParameterValueStruct>
<ParameterValueStruct>
<Name>InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Username</Name>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">rock3</Value>
</ParameterValueStruct>
</ParameterList>
</cwmp:Inform>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

my code below:

```
class DeviceId(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  Manufacturer = String
  OUI          = String
  ProductClass = String
  SerialNumber = String

class EventStruct(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  EventCode   = String
  CommandKey  = String

class Event(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  EventStruct = EventStruct

class ParameterValueStruct(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  Name  = String
  Value = String

class ParameterList(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  ParameterValueStruct = ParameterValueStruct

class CWMP(ServiceBase):
  @srpc(DeviceId, Event, Integer, String, Integer, Array(ParameterList), _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
  def Inform(DeviceId, Event, MaxEnvelopes, CurrentTime, RetryCount, ParameterList):
    pList = []
    for i in ParameterList:
      print i.ParameterValueStruct
      pList.append(i.ParameterValueStruct.Name)
    print DeviceId
    print Event
    print Event.EventStruct.EventCode
    print MaxEnvelopes
    print CurrentTime
    ...
```

Get all variable normally except ParameterList

```
(Pdb) type(i)
<class '__main__.ParameterList'>
(Pdb) type(i.ParameterValueStruct)
<type 'NoneType'>
(Pdb) print i
ParameterList()
(Pdb) print i.ParameterValueStruct
None
```

Does anybody got an idea of how to get all Name/Value in ParameterValueStruct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I fixed:

1. You don't need Array() when you're defining wrapper objects manually
2. Spyne doesn't support soap:enc attrs.
3. You need a proper namespace for the child tags of `<cwmp:Inform>` if you want to use lxml validation.
4. It's better for you to use _type_info notation if you want to control the order of the elements

Code:

```
class DeviceId(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  _type_info = [
    ('Manufacturer', String),
    ('OUI',          String),
    ('ProductClass', String),
    ('SerialNumber', String),
  ]

class EventStruct(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  EventCode   = String
  CommandKey  = String

class Event(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  EventStruct = EventStruct.customize(max_occurs='unbounded')

class ParameterValueStruct(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  Name  = String
  Value = String

class ParameterList(ComplexModel):
  __namespace__ = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0"
  ParameterValueStruct = ParameterValueStruct.customize(max_occurs='unbounded')

class CWMP(ServiceBase):
  @srpc(DeviceId, Event, Integer, String, Integer, ParameterList, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
  def Inform(DeviceId, Event, MaxEnvelopes, CurrentTime, RetryCount, ParameterList):
    pList = []
    for i in ParameterList.ParameterValueStruct:
      print i
      pList.append(i.Name)
    print DeviceId
    print Event
    print Event.EventStruct[0].EventCode
    print MaxEnvelopes
    print CurrentTime


application = Application([CWMP], 'urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0',
            in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
            out_protocol=Soap11()
        )
```

Request:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <cwmp:ID soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">984890494</cwmp:ID>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <cwmp:Inform xmlns="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">
            <DeviceId>
                <Manufacturer>xxxx</Manufacturer>
                <OUI>xxxxxx</OUI>
                <ProductClass>x-xxxx-xx</ProductClass>
                <SerialNumber>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</SerialNumber>
            </DeviceId>
            <Event>
                <EventStruct>
                    <EventCode>2 PERIODIC</EventCode>
                    <CommandKey/>
                </EventStruct>
            </Event>
            <MaxEnvelopes>1</MaxEnvelopes>
            <CurrentTime>2014-05-21T10:47:37+08:00</CurrentTime>
            <RetryCount>56</RetryCount>
            <ParameterList>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary</Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SpecVersion</Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.HardwareVersion
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3FE55918ABAA</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.SoftwareVersion
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3FE55935ADEA19</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.ProvisioningCode
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">123</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>
                        InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ConnectionRequestURL
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://x.x.x.x:7547/</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.ParameterKey
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>
                        InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANIPConnection.1.ExternalIPAddress
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">10.18.92.182</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>
                        InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.2.WANIPConnection.1.MACAddress
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
                <ParameterValueStruct>
                    <Name>
                        InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.1.Username
                    </Name>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">rock3</Value>
                </ParameterValueStruct>
            </ParameterList>
        </cwmp:Inform>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: it is useful. thanks. how to set child tags of <cwmp:Inform> ?